# Draw a RoundRect in easeljs

Tags: createjs, easeljs

How to draw a rectangle in easeljs with only two rounded corners. I am doing this to get rounded corners in the bottom:

```
layout.graphics.beginStroke("black").drawRoundRect(100,100,100,100,0,0,5,5);
```

This is not drawing any rounded corners. Only this seems to be working:

```
layout.graphics.beginStroke("black").drawRoundRect(100,100,100,100,5);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the `drawRoundRectComplex` method, instead of `drawRoundRect`: http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.html#method_drawRoundRectComplex

```
drawRoundRectComplex(x, y, w, h, radiusTL, radiusTR, radiusBR, radiusBL);
```

Hope that helps.